# Is byte[] to UTF8 to JSON string a safe encoding for binary data?

Tags: c#, encoding

I'm looking to log the body of HTML POST requests to my web API in a text file.  I want it so that "human-readable" characters will be easily viewable, so I don't want to encode it to base64, but I also need all the non-"human-readable" bytes to be safely encoded so that they can always be restored to a `byte[]` which is exactly the same as the input array.

Will the following code always safely store all non-readable bytes as JSON escape sequences, while storing readable characters as themselves?

```
byte[] bodyBytes = GetBodyBytes(ctx);
var bodyString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bodyBytes);
var safeString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { bodyString });
```

One problem I can see immediately is that this will store newline sequences simply as `\n`, losing the data about whether they used the Windows- or Unix-style newline bytes.  How can I avoid losing any such data while keeping things human readable where possible?

Comment: All the other control characters may also be a problem; a different encoding is probably a better idea

Comment: Remember, when you go from your byte array to a string, you are *de*coding. Not all sequences of bytes validly represent UTF-8 data. Also, the example code you show does not use `bodyString` after computing it.

Comment: Converting raw binary data to an UTF-8 string is never a good idea. UTF-8 is a complex spec with a lot of unexpected special cases that might affect your data. Why don't you keep the data as byte[] and parse it directly from byte[]?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That was a mistake; edited.

Comment: @Robert I can; I was hoping there was some standard 'safe' way to do this, so that lots of readable characters like `[a-z-A-Z0-9]` etc. would be represented literally, and thus quickly readable, and everything else would be escaped.  I could probably roll my own but it'd be better if someone had already done it.

Comment: That said, are you sure your JSON serialization will convert newlines? The JSON format does allow for representing carriage return and line feed characters individually with escape sequences (`\r\n`).

Comment: If the question is simply "what's the name of that encoding that interprets each single byte as a character, mapping them to the first 256 Unicode code points in order?", that's `latin-1` or `iso-8859-1`.

Comment: If it's a mixture of binary with text data within it... how do you know which parts are _supposed_ to be text in the first place? You need to know which bits are text (and what encoding that text is in) so you can render them properly, in which case you're talking about needing to parse the entire body so you know what's what, otherwise you could just be rendering gibberish and missing actual text etc.

Comment: The parts that are supposed to be text, for the purposes of this exercise, are safely-displayable ASCII characters.  I don't care if some parts of binary data get encoded literally and look like gibberish (and other parts encoded), as long as it can reliably be turned back into the same source byte array.  I suppose I'm probably asking for something custom enough that I need to just roll my own and have a method that checks whether the byte is within a well-defined set of bytes in order to determine whether to encode it literally or using an escape sequence.

Comment: To be honest, looking at the ASCII table, I probably just need a method that encodes all bytes that aren't between 32 and 126... with the slight complication that backslash (byte  92) would need to also be escaped as it would itself be used for escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I rolled my own encoding, as my requirements are probably too specific for an existing encoding scheme to implement completely.  Here's the method I created:

```
private string UltraSafeEncode(byte[] bytes) {
    if (bytes == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bytes));
    }

    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    foreach (var thisByte in bytes) {
        if (thisByte < 32 || thisByte == 92 || thisByte > 126) {
            sb.Append('\\').AppendFormat("{0:x2}", thisByte);
            continue;
        }

        sb.Append((char)thisByte);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```